# Multiple @RabbitListeners sending reply to same queue when using sendAndReceive() in producer

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, rpc, spring-amqp

I am using SpringBoot with Spring AMQP and I want to use RPC pattern using synchronous sendAndReceive method in producer. My configuration assumes 1 exchange with 2 distinct bindings (1 for each operation on the same resource). I want to send 2 messages with 2 different routingKeys and receive response on distinct reply-to queues

Problem is, as far as I know, sendAndReceive will wait for reply on a queue with name ".replies" so both replies will be sent to `products.replies` queue (at least that is my understanding).

My publisher config:

```
    @Bean
    public DirectExchange productsExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("products");
    }

    @Bean
    public OrderService orderService() {
        return new MqOrderService();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
```

and the 2 senders:

```
...
final Message response = template.sendAndReceive(productsExchange.getName(), "products.get", message);
...

final Message response = template.sendAndReceive(productsExchange.getName(), "products.stock.update", message);

...
```

consumer config:

```
    @Bean
    public Queue getProductQueue() {
        return new Queue("getProductBySku");
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue updateStockQueue() {
        return new Queue("updateProductStock");
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange("products");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding getProductBinding(DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(getProductQueue())
                .to(exchange)
                .with("products.get");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding modifyStockBinding(DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(updateStockQueue())
                .to(exchange)
                .with("products.stock.update");
    }
```

and @RabbitListeners with following sigratures:

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "getProductBySku")
    public Message getProduct(GetProductResource getProductResource) {...}

 @RabbitListener(queues = "updateProductStock")
    public Message updateStock(UpdateStockResource updateStockResource) {...}
```

I noticed that the second sender receives 2 responses, one of which is of invalid type (from first receiver). Is there any way in which I can make these connections distinct? Or is using separate exchange for each operation the only reasonable solution?

Answer (score 2):

> as far as I know, sendAndReceive will wait for reply on a queue with name ".replies"

Where did you get that idea?

Depending on which version you are using, either a temporary reply queue will be created for each request or RabbitMQ's "direct reply-to" mechanism is used, which again means each request is replied to on a dedicated pseudo queue called `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to`.

I don't see any way for one producer to get another's reply; even if you use an explicit reply container (which is generally not necessary any more), the template will correlate the replies to the requests.

Try enabling DEBUG logging to see if provides any hints.